# Spring Boot 1.3 Oauth2 Sso return 401 instead of redirect to authorization server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

With Spring Boot 1.3 there is an autoconfiguration for Oauth2 in Spring Boot.

There is a [spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2) which provides a few nice examples, but i want to achieve a different solution. 
My problem bases on the provided [click](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_click) example. 
I want to be redirected to the authorization server after visiting the "/login" endpoint. If i request a protected resource without authentication i want to get a 401 (Unauthorized) instead of instant a redirect (302) to the authorization uri.

This is Java code of the click example

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @RequestMapping("/user")
  public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

I tried adding a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint but it seems that this is just ignored :(

What i tried:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http401AuthenticationEntryPoint("Session realm=\"JSESSIONID\""));
  }
```

The full source code of the click example can be found on [github](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/click).

Is it possible to achieve a 401 instead of the redirect?

Comment: i did not understand, do you want achieve a 401 error for all resources? Or you need some pages with 401 and another's with redirect?

Comment: 401 on all resources except /login. /login should redirect to the authorization server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until spring-boot 1.3.0 it was impossible to do so due to an issue in the order of applying custom configurers when using this combination (see [#4629 for further resolution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4629)).

Starting with spring-boot 1.3.1 the request header `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` signals that the caller prefers a `401 Unauthorized` over a `302 Found`